# Como puedo crear un valor de un parametro que no obtengo de un JSON response?

Tags: python, json, django

Estoy haciendo una APP en la que quiero obtener data del usuario: nombre, ID, email, etc. Pero la API que estoy utilizando a veces no manda el correo del usuario, en estos casos la app simplemente me devuelve None y al momento de querer interactuar con este Key, me lanza un KeyError.

Quisiera poder crear en estos casos una string vacia o al menos un valor para evitar ese KeyError

```py
errors = {}

try:
    if not email:
        errors['email'] = _(u'Falta ingresar este dato.')
    else:
        validate_email(email)
        if email != user_data['email']:
            if user_data['email'] in ["", None]:
                user_data['email'] = email
            # Si modificó el mail, ya no está verificado y veo si ya está registrado por otro usuario
            if 'email_verified' in user_data:
                user_data['email_verified'] = False
            users_same_mail = User.objects.filter(email=email)
            if users_same_mail.exists():
                # Existen otros usuarios que tienen el mismo mail, y no es el que le dió al sistema
                # Se le puede dar al sistema un mail ya cargado para otro user
                errors['email'] = _(
                    u'El correo electrónico ya se encuentra registrado.')

except ValidationError as e:
    errors['email'] = _(
        u'El correo electrónico no es válido, por favor intentá de nuevo.')
```

Algun consejo en particular de que podria agregar para crear un valor de email en los casos donde no obtenga nada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta a tu pregunta depende de la decisión de diseño que hayas elegido en el caso de que no llegue el correo por parte de un usuario.

¿Tu aplicación debería retornar un error o debería permitir la creación de un usuario sin email?

Asumiendo que debería funcionar puedes checkear antes de acceder a los valores de ese diccionario si existe la llave `'email'`, y colocar un valor por defecto si es necesario.

Algo así:

```
if 'email' not in user_data.keys():
    user_data['email'] = None
```

En caso que debiese fallar con un error deberías utilizar el mismo if para producir un mensaje de falla.

De todas maneras, te recomiendo atrapar las excepciones de `KeyError` para retornar una respuesta de `Bad Request` al clente, dado que si falla el programa por eso produce un `Internal Server Error`, lo cual resulta menos útil para el cliente al momento de depurar.

```
except KeyError as e:
    errors['email'] = _(
        u'Error en los datos enviados')
```

Comment: Gracias! Ayer habia llegado a esta conclusión, lo que hice fue agregar la key obligatoriamente si no la reconoce.